# How to download and install DLC in UWP Application?

Tags: uwp

I want to implement DLC content to my UWP app to reduce its size, with possibility to install DLC packages from code. Looks like optional packages are what I need. But to install optional package from code I need to use StoreContext.RequestDownloadAndInstallStorePackagesAsync or PackageCatalog.AddOptionalPackageAsync(). But both methods have notes, that them not avaliable to all developer accounts. Also PackageCatalog.AddOptionalPackageAsync() have a note that it can be used only for optional packages in a related set. For publish optional packages in a related set needed special permission from Windows, and answer from Windows support: "Unfortunately, they have denied the request to use optional packages with related sets".
Is there some other way to use DLC in my app?

Comment: I’m afraid you can’t do this without using optional package. There is no other way to solve it, currently, uwp only provides optional package to download and install DLC.

Comment: Can you clarify, can I use StoreContext.RequestDownloadAndInstallStorePackagesAsync to download and install optional package without code (only content)? I'm successfully submitted such package to store, but StoreContext.RequestDownloadAndInstallStorePackagesAsync finishing with error ERROR:No products found. I used StoreId for my optional package. Is there some tricks? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, you can. In addition, Micorsoft App store takes some time (approx. 24 hours) to enable the products/add-ons to programming APIs. So please wait patiently.

Comment: I submitted package to store at 08 Apr 2021, so looks like it's not time-to-enable issue. 
I created optional package (not in related set) by tutorial: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/appinstaller/build-your-first-optional-package.
Should I somehow tell store that it's optional package without code and it can be installed by API in my main app? Or I need to package it with makeappx.exe, to exclude all code from it?
And is there some restrictions for API to "find" such package in store, can it be "Private audience" and "available but not discoverable in the Microsoft Store"?

Comment: Let's back to the beginning, you mentioned that you failed to get permission to submit this app that uses optional packages. Could you please tell me if you have gotten this permission successfully?

Comment: I  failed to get permission to submit my main app with related set definition in it. So I submitted my main app without  related set definition. And I submitted my optional package (only content, not in related set) as separate package to store. I can install my optional package manually from store and use it content in my main app. But I can't install it from code, by calling StoreContext.RequestDownloadAndInstallStorePackagesAsync with StoreId of my optional package - it finishing with error ERROR:No products found.

Comment: The behavior you get is expected. You need to get this permission, so that the Microsoft Store can associate this optional package with your app, then you could download it through code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research I found that I can upload DLC (optional packages, only content, not in related set, link to description: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/optional-packages) to store, install them manually and use in my main app.
But if you need to install DLC from code, you need special permission from Microsoft to use optional packages, so that the Microsoft Store can associate this optional package with your app, and then you could download it through code.
With permission new field will appear in Partner centre->Product->Create new add-on menu. If you choose Durable add-on, you'll have new option "Enable package upload", where you can upload your optional packages. Add-ons have StoreIds, so, using them you can later download these packages from code with StoreContext.RequestDownloadAndInstallStorePackagesAsync Method. Also you can uninstall installed optional packages with PackageCatalog.RemoveOptionalPackagesAsync.